# Direct download using curl on a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I'm trying to download a file directly from a link but I need to use the Curl, the direct link is not valid, no security restrictions on the server, for direct access.

Just need to access the link via curl and perform the download.

Use something like this:

/ * php script * /

```
$ url = "http://server:8080/system/downloads/idfile"; 
$ ch = curl_init (); 
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ url); 
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true); 
$ data = curl_exec ($ ch); 
curl_close ($ ch); 
return $ data;
```

/ * end script * /

I used some headers before return, but file format doc, xls, ppt return corrupted

```
header ("Content-type: application/msword"); 
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.doc");
```

Could help me to download the file directly by clicking button in an html page and run the script curl up?

Currently I am using codeigniter where the curl of this script in a controller , and action will be implemented through a link in a view

thanks

Comment: Did you tried to use the port option of curl ?

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 8080);`

Comment: Set the proper `header()`s and then `exit($data);` because `return $data;` is wrong for this unless your cURL is inside function1 being called from function2 and function2 has the `header()` code but even so you want to `exit($data);` inside function2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this am always using this code.

```
function get_all_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$returned_content = get_all_data('https://www.connectedcommerce.net/');
file_put_contents('open.txt',$returned_content,FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: That way did not work. 

There is no data returned. The link to access the call is a method to download from another system, and so the use of restricted direct access to the link. 
 
Smpre I call the method through the curl, but not to any return. The download method works because the tested

Answer (score 0):

That way did not work. There is no data returned. The link to access the call is a method to download from another system, and so the use of restricted direct access to the link. Smpre I call the method through the curl, but not to any return. The download method works because the tested